# Use windows 8 default icon set outside appbar

Tags: html, windows-8

Is it possible to use the windows 8 (javascript) icons which can be used in the app bar outside of the appbar as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be more accurate, this code replicates the same behavior & design, and also supports the icon label below:

```
<button class="win-command win-global win-hidefocus" id="btnCamera" role="menuitem" aria-label="Camera" type="button">
    <span tabindex="-1" class="win-commandicon win-commandring" aria-hidden="true">
        <span tabindex="-1" class="win-commandimage" aria-hidden="true">&#xE114;</span>
    </span>
    <span tabindex="-1" class="win-label" aria-hidden="true">Front Camera</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Didn't test that out, but trusting you that that works, that's a better answer than mine :D .

Answer (score 1):

This was extremely hard to find, if you're expecting it to be an image rather than a character from a font (and Google didn't give any useful results) and even once you know that it takes awhile to extract all the right styles, so it seemed to be a good idea to share this on here.

Below I have included an example of a valid replica button:

```
<button style="border:2px solid black;min-width:0px;min-height:0px;border-radius:50%;height:41px;line-height:37px;width:41px;font-size:14pt;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0px; background:white;color:black;font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Ebrima', 'Nirmala UI', 'Gadugi', 'Segoe UI Symbol', 'Meiryo UI', 'Khmer UI', 'Tunga', 'Lao UI', 'Raavi', 'Iskoola Pota', 'Latha', 'Leelawadee', 'Microsoft YaHei UI', 'Microsoft JhengHei UI', 'Malgun Gothic', 'Estrangelo Edessa', 'Microsoft Himalaya', 'Microsoft New Tai Lue', 'Microsoft PhagsPa', 'Microsoft Tai Le', 'Microsoft Yi Baiti', 'Mongolian Baiti', 'MV Boli', 'Myanmar Text', 'Cambria Math'; display: inline-block; text-align: center;" type="button">&#xE124;</button>
```

For the character codes I would recommend looking inside a C++ webstore project inside the standardStyles xml file.

Comment: Please told me where to find the `HEX` for buttons ? like you :`&#xE124;`

Comment: Check the xml file I reference in my answer ;-) If I remember correctly they were in there. And use Morians answer for the html.

Comment: I found it..@David Mulder but i am not able to write this char code dynamically using java-script ! Do yu have any idea how to add it dynamically?

Comment: What do you mean with "writing them dynamically"?

Comment: I create an array ` icon: ['&#xE13E', '&#xE197', '&#xE159', '&#xE107'],` and add them one by one to dynamically created buttons so, `var buttons = $("<button id='" + button.id[i] + "' class='win-commandring win-commandicon' title='" + button.tooltip[i] + "'>" + button.icon[i] + "</button>");` but they are empty in result..@David Mulder

Comment: But it works when you put it straight into the button? Because it seems to me that you're missing the `spans` with the correct classes the  which I believe define the necessary glyph font.

Comment: Ya, i also add those, same problem ,they appears empty ! but when i put them directly they are shown... i want to add in this way ?why they became empty when add dynamically ?@David Mulder

Comment: Using the chrome inspector (as the IE inspector is still crap), do you see any difference between generated and non-generated HTML?

Comment: I found my `error`,i made a silly mistake ,not put `;` at the last of every `CharCode`, So it works After , `icon: ['&#xE13E;', '&#xE197;', '&#xE159;', '&#xE107;']` Thanks to being the part..

Answer (score 0):

Too late but ,I share my snippet that how i achieve this :

**Without label :**

```
<button id='buttonid' class='win-commandring win-commandicon' title='tooltip'>&#xE159;</button>
```

**With label :**

```
<div style='text-align:center'>
<button class='win-commandring win-commandicon'>&#xE159;</button><br>
Save as
</div>
```

**Don't forget to use `Semi-colon`(`;`) after every Char code.*

And if you want to See the *Char Code for Icon's* then ->

**Open :**

```
Start Menu -> Type " character Map " -> Press Enter
```

Now a `Window opens -> Select -> Font : 'Segoe UI Symbol'`

See below where you can find all Char code for ***ICONS ON WINDOWS 8***

[image: ICON SET WINDOWS 8]

Maybe it will help full !